# How to check if any values in an array is not null in Dataweave 2.0?

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule-component, mulesoft

I am mapping my payload to a new payload and adding an Errors array in where the output looks like this. :

```
payload : [{

"test: "test",

 "test2" : "",

 "test3" : "test3"

},
{

"test: "test",

 "test2" : "test2",

 "test3" : "test3"

}]
```

Expected output : ` payload : [{

```
"test: "test",

 "test2" : "",

 "test3" : "test3",

 "Errors" : {

  "test2" : "Test2 is NULL"

  }

},
{

"test: "test",

 "test2" : "test2",

 "test3" : "test3",

 "Errors" : {

  }

}]`
```

Expected Output : I want to get an output where I only get all objects from Payload where Errors array has any key with not null values otherwise it should be filtered out.

I am using below expression to achieve but this is not feasible as it requires me to add a null check for each key in Errors array.

```
errArr."Errors" filter ((item, index) -> item."test" != "" or item."test2" != "" or

item."test3" != "")
```

There has to be a better way to do this? Is there a way to just check values of every item (key)without defining their name?

Comment: Just for the record the empty string is not `null` in Dataweave.

Comment: yes, I understand that. my goal here is to either addd errors to the array only if the validation fails for a specific key and if that is not possible, I need to extract success row (no error in errors).

Comment: Create an exprected output because your sentence: `I want to get an output where I only get all objects from Payload where Errors array has any key with not null values otherwise it should be filtered out.` makes little sense to me.  Form what I can gather based upon your specific input you should have an empty array.

Comment: @George sorry about that, I was allover the place, I updated the input output, I hope it's a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, explanations follow the code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = [{
    "test": "test",
     "test2" : "",
     "test3" : "test3"
    },
    {
    "test": "test",
     "test2" : "test2",
     "test3" : "test3"
    
    }
]

---
data map {
    ($),
    errors: $ mapObject (v,k) -> (
        if (isEmpty(v)) {(k): "$(k) is empty"} else {}
    )
}
```

Here's the algorithm along with links in the documentation:

1. Iterate over the objects in the array using [`map`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-map)
2. Create a new object and add the existing (key,value) pairs in the new object
   using the [dynamic elements](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#dynamic_elements) feature.
3. Add the `errors` field to the new object.  Calculate the `errors` object using the [`mapObject`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-mapobject) function that identifies all empty (notice I say empty and not just `null`) fields.

My advice to you is to ensure you provide an appropriately scoped input and output set of sample data when you ask questions.  This will ensure that you will get your answers to your questions in a more timely basis.

Comment: my fault on input output, This does solve the problem but problem is not all validations are just NULL/ Empty check. But I will accept this as a solution for now as I was able to get what I exactly want from these answers with some tweaks. Thank you again for explaining, this is super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are a few errors in your input.

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
import * from dw::core::Objects
output application/json
---
payload map {
    ($),
    Errors: $ 
                filterObject ((value, key) ->  isEmpty(value)) 
                mapObject ((value, key) ->  (key): key ++ " is NULL") 
}
```

Input:

```
[
    {
        "test": "test",
        "test2" : "",
        "test3" : "test3"
    },
    {
        "test": "test",
        "test2" : "test2",
        "test3" : "test3"
    }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "test": "test",
    "test2": "",
    "test3": "test3",
    "Errors": {
      "test2": "test2 is NULL"
    }
  },
  {
    "test": "test",
    "test2": "test2",
    "test3": "test3",
    "Errors": {
      
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: it works partially, let's say I had first object in array where Errors array has no error al are blank and then second object in array has some errors,

When I try this with ***not*** it does not give accurate result : `payload filter (valuesOf($.Errors) some not ($ != ""))`

Basically I am trying to get object where all keys in errors are "". How can I get those objects?

Comment: Please update examples of the different cases *and* add the expected output for each. Otherwise it is very difficult to understand what is being required.

Comment: I updated my answer to match the new input and outputs. Please specify them in all future questions.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time on this.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

**Input**

```
[{
 "test": "test",
 "test2" : "test2",
 "test3" : "test3",
 "Errors" : {
  "test": null,
  "test2" : "Test2 is NULL",
  "test3" : ""
  }
},
{
 "test": "1231test123",
 "test2" : "123test23232",
 "test3" : "12421test3",
 "Errors" : {
  "test": "",
  "test2" : "",
  "test3" : ""
  }
},
{
 "test": "3asdsadasd",
 "test2" : "123123",
 "test3" : "d323e2d23",
 "Errors" : {
  "test": "123",
  "test2" : "",
  "test3" : ""
  }
}
]
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
import * from dw::core::Objects
output application/json
---
payload -- (payload map $ filter ( valuesOf( $.Errors ) some ( !isEmpty($) and ($ != null) and sizeOf($) >0)))
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "test": "1231test123",
    "test2": "123test23232",
    "test3": "12421test3",
    "Errors": {
      "test": "",
      "test2": "",
      "test3": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Or you could use just the !isEmpty and still get to the desired by removing that from the initial payload by doing a payload -- (derived fields that meet the condition)

Comment: that is precisely what I am looking for but here as you said, is there a way I can only add those errors to the Errors object if the validation fails? In that case I just need to check the size Of Errors object to see if there are any errors. I can ask another question if it helps?